# TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key при построении графиков коэффициента детерминации

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn

Имеется код Python который должен выводить графики коэффициентов детерминации по различным регрессионным моделям:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

dataset = pd.read_csv('1.csv', ';')


dataset = dataset.drop(['X1', 'X4'], axis=1)
dataset.head()

trg = dataset[['Y1', 'Y2']]
trn = dataset.drop(['Y1', 'Y2'], axis=1)

models = [LinearRegression(),  # метод наименьших квадратов
          RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, max_features='sqrt'),  # случайный лес
          KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=6),  # метод ближайших соседей
          SVR(kernel='linear'),  # метод опорных векторов с линейным ядром
          LogisticRegression()  # логистическая регрессия
          ]
Xtrn, Xtest, Ytrn, Ytest = train_test_split(trn, trg, test_size=0.4)

TestModels = DataFrame()
tmp = {}
# для каждой модели из списка
for model in models:
    # получаем имя модели
    m = str(model)
    tmp['Model'] = m[:m.index('(')]
    # для каждого столбца результирующего набора
    for i in range(Ytrn.shape[1]):
        # обучаем модель
        model.fit(Xtrn, Ytrn[:, i])
        # вычисляем коэффициент детерминации
        tmp['R2_Y%s' % str(i + 1)] = r2_score(Ytest[:, 0], model.predict(Xtest))
    # записываем данные и итоговый DataFrame
    TestModels = TestModels.append([tmp])
# делаем индекс по названию модели
TestModels.set_index('Model', inplace=True)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 4))
TestModels.R2_Y1.plot(ax=axes[0], kind='bar', title='R2_Y1')
TestModels.R2_Y2.plot(ax=axes[1], kind='bar', color='green', title='R2_Y2')

plt.show()
```

При запуске кода получаем стек:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ivmec\Desktop\Regression\Lineregress.py", line 39, in <module>
    model.fit(Xtrn, Ytrn[:, i])
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\workspace-env-3.9\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\workspace-env-3.9\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 75, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Очевидно ошибка возникает при обращении к массивам, каким образом возможно исправление ошибки?

DataFrame сохраненный в 1.csv с разделителем ";" имеет следующий вид:

```
;X1;X2;X3;X4;X5;X6;X7;X8;Y1;Y2
0;0.98;514.5;294.0;110.25;7;2;0;0;15.55;21.33
1;0.98;514.5;294.0;110.25;7;3;0;0;15.55;21.33
2;0.98;514.5;294.0;110.25;7;4;0;0;15.55;21.33
3;0.98;514.5;294.0;110.25;7;5;0;0;15.55;21.33
4;0.90;563.5;318.5;122.50;7;2;0;0;20.84;28.28
```

Comment: Но ведь вы используете сепаратор `;`, приведите файл с этим сепаратором, чтобы можно было воспроизвести вашу проблему на вашем коде.

Comment: А вообще вы проверяли, что у вас получилось в `Xtrn`, `Ytrn`?

Comment: Представил фрайм с учетом сепаратора. В Xtrn массив согласно введённым данным из фрейма содержит X2, X3, X5-X8 с соответствующим количеством наблюдений из фрейма. В Ytrn соответственно массив содержащий Y1 и Y2 с соответствующим количеством наблюдений из фрейма.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Везде, где вы используете такую конструкцию (и такую тоже `Ytest[:, 0]`):

```
Ytrn[:, i]
```

Нужно использовать `.iloc` (либо `.loc` для символьных индексов), как это рекомендуется в документации по `Pandas` уже довольно давно:

```
Ytrn.iloc[:, i]
```

У вас там ещё ошибки есть, в частности для использования метода ближайших соседей с шестью соседями:

```
KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=6)
```

У вас слишком мало данных, заработает только с двумя соседями:

```
KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=2)
```

Ну и `LogisticRegression()` предназначена для классификации, она конечно отказывается работать на ваших данных, предназначенных для задачи регрессии.

После этих исправлений программа работает и рисует какие-то графики.

Comment: Большое спасибо, понял свои ошибки.